# Locking a table with a select in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, transactionscope, table-locking

I need to do something like this

```
select * from myTable with (xlock,holdlock)
```

using Entity Framework. Is this possible? I've opened a `TransactionScope` with the `Serializable` isolation level but my selects are not locking the tables. I'd like them to lock until I complete the transaction scope.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible but you have to issue the SQL you can't add the locking hint when using LINQ (as far as I know):

```
ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(
                string.Format("select 1 from [{0}] with (tablockx, holdlock) where 0 = 1",
                              tableName));
```

If you do that in a transaction scope then you'll hold the lock until you complete the transaction.

A bit more information can be found here:

http://peplowdown.wordpress.com/2010/07/18/locking-across-servers-table-locks-with-entity-framework/